# CSS Flexbox and Grid: is the order's default value 0 or 1?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

In Flexbox and Grid, we can change the order in which items are displayed, with among other things the `order` property. Everywhere, I'm reading that the default `order` value is `0`, also on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items.

But look at this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Order demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
    body {
        margin: 40px;
    }
    .wrapper {
        width: 600px;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 100px);
        grid-gap: 10px;
    }
    .box {
        background-color: #444;
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 20px;
        font-size: 150%;
        order: 1;
    }
    .box:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #ccc;
        color: #000;
    }
    .box2 {
        order: 0;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="box box1">1</div>
        <div class="box box2">2</div>
        <div class="box box3">3</div>
        <div class="box box4">4</div>
        <div class="box box5">5</div>
        <div class="box box6">6</div>
        <div class="box box7">7</div>
        <div class="box box8">8</div>
        <div class="box box9">9</div>
        <div class="box box10">10</div>
        <div class="box box11">11</div>
        <div class="box box12">12</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the corresponding Pen, in which you can see the rendering: https://codepen.io/FrankConijn/pen/BaYxBzd.

Item nr. 2 is displayed first, while it has `order: 0`, which should have it displayed in the order in which it is placed in the code (2nd). That suggests that the specs are incorrect, and that the default value is 1. Am I right?

Comment: But all other `box`es have `order: 1` set...? If you remove this style declaration all elements have either `order: 0` by default or in the case of `.box2` explicit set which results in the original order (1, 2, 3, ..., 12)

Comment: You're right! Silly me! I played around with and forked someone else's Pen and had missed that she had given all items an `order: 1` previously. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`order` does indeed have a default value of `0` ([MDN formal definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order#formal_definition) & [MDN 'Ordering Flex Items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items#the_order_property)'), but in your example you've overridden this by giving each `.box` an explicit `order: 1`; here the `order: 0` on `.box2` is behaving correctly according to its property in appearing in the 1st position.

If you remove the order on your `.box` class and let them order by default (0) you'll see that the position of `.box2` is placed as it should be: as the 2nd box:

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 100px);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.box:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #000;
}

.box2 {
  order: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box box1">1</div>
    <div class="box box2">2</div>
    <div class="box box3">3</div>
    <div class="box box4">4</div>
    <div class="box box5">5</div>
    <div class="box box6">6</div>
    <div class="box box7">7</div>
    <div class="box box8">8</div>
    <div class="box box9">9</div>
    <div class="box box10">10</div>
    <div class="box box11">11</div>
    <div class="box box12">12</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You're right! Silly me! I played around with and forked someone else's Pen and had missed that she had given all items an `order: 1` previously. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: No problem; I thought it was some kind of trick question at first! 